# Objective-c coding convention?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

In objective-c,can i declare a UI variable with type?:

```
UIButton *btn_Add,*btn_showMessage or UILabel *lb_Title
```

How about: `UIButton *btnAdd,*btnShowMessage or *lbTitle`
Thanks so much

Comment: You're also missing the `*`s, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [coding guidlines for Cocoa: Code Naming Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH):

- In general, don’t abbreviate names of things. Spell them out, even if they’re long.
- For names composed of multiple words, do not use punctuation marks as parts of names or as separators (underscores, dashes, and so on); instead, capitalize the first letter of each word and run the words together (for example, runTheWordsTogether)—this is known as camel-casing.
- It is good to be both clear and brief as possible, but clarity shouldn’t suffer because of brevity.
- Names shouldn’t be self-referential.

So yeah, either what nonamelive proposed, or try to get rid of "button" prefix/suffix as well if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `addButton`, `showMessageButton`, `titleLabel`, etc.